# YouTube API "published" filter doesn't seem to work

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube API to return videos that were recently published, but the filter I'm using doesn't seem to work as expected.

This API call only returns two videos whereas there should be tons more that were published after March 1st:

> [https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=&fields=entry[xs:dateTime(published)%20%3E%20xs:dateTime('2013-03-01T12:00:00.000Z')]](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=&fields=entry%5Bxs%3adateTime%28published%29%20%3E%20xs%3adateTime%28%272013-03-01T12:00:00.000Z%27%29%5D)

However, if I add a query string, then many more results are returned. For example:

> [https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&fields=entry[xs:dateTime(published)%20%3E%20xs:dateTime('2013-03-01T12:00:00.000Z')]](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&fields=entry%5Bxs%3adateTime%28published%29%20%3E%20xs%3adateTime%28%272013-03-01T12:00:00.000Z%27%29%5D)

Anyone know why? Is there another approach I should be using to just get me the latest videos published regardless of query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion, but that's not what the `fields=` parameter is used for. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial) should hopefully clear things up, but to summarize, using `fields=` in that manner is equivalent to making a request without the `fields=` parameter and then filtering the results of that request so that it only includes the entries that match your filter.

So if your request without `fields=` would normally return 25 specific videos, adding `fields=` to it will give you a response that includes somewhere between 0 and 25 videos—all the non-matching videos are filtered out.

You can request a feed of recently published videos without any other filters using http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&orderby=published

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks Jeff!